# SharePoint 2013 Search Results for Site Search Box and Document Library

Tags: sharepoint

I like to check if there is a way to allow Document Library Search feature to function but when user tries to search in Main Site Search Box, document library items are not returned in the result list?

I have tried to add search query but it does not work.

Thank you.

Comment: The Main Site Search Box is for searching items that are indexed by the Search Service Application. In order to search the items in the document library you need to create Result Source

Comment: HI Martin, does it means that I can exclude the document library from being indexed and still have be able to search the items in document library by creating Result Source?

Comment: Hello Tohz. Yes, you can exclude the document library from being indexed. Here is a reference that points out how to do that (https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8f405926-c253-43d9-8372-ce9dd441e6cb/exclude-document-library-from-crawl?forum=sharepointsearch). In the Result Source you can't search in the documents content but you can search the items (documents) in the Document Library even they are not indexed

Comment: Martin, I have tried to exclude the document from being indexed and adding of the Result Source. However, it does not seems to work to search items in Document Library. For the Result Source, is there any specific query that I need to use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done this myself but I think you would need to go in to the site settings and play around with the Search area to get something like this to work. I think the area you would have to tinker with would be Result sources.

Hope this helps

Cheers

Truez